# Failed to Send data with external file.js to php using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript

**put the javascript code directly in the HTML page, it does work. Howcome it does not work if I reference the script using the src attribute on the script**
This is my HTML page:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can not get the following javascript code to send data to a PHP page:
this is inside file.js

```js
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'server.php';
var params = 'a=use&b=12345678';
http.open('POST', url, true); // error javascript stop always here
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
{ alert(http.responseText); } }
http.send(params);
```

and this is inside `server.php`:

```php
<?php
$username = $_POST['a'];
$password = $_POST['b'];
echo 'username :' . $username;
?>
```

When I put the javascript code directly in the HTML page, it does work. Howcome it does not work if I reference the script using the `src` attribute on the `script` tag?
for example when i put the file.js script in online compiler like 'playcode.io' it does not work

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? IE 11 is the only thing lacking support. It'll make your life a million times easier if you don't need to support IE 11. If you do need IE support, though... not so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: no it's not a duplicate

Comment: No solution after 2 Week

Comment: @MYARCH What is your files architecture ? Are the HTML and JS files in the same folder ?

Comment: html and js not in the same folder i need to call js file from external link

Comment: @MYARCH So do you update the url variable in the JS consequently ?

Comment: i call the file.js  in html using ´´´     <script src="file.js"></script>
´´´ and  the file.js content the xmlhttprequest() function i note that the error came in line http.open

Comment: @MYARCH Are the JS and PHP files in the same folder ? If not, you have to give the correct path in the url variable. Like for example `var url = '..\\server.php';`

Comment: the path is correct i note that xmlhttprequest treat like undefined with file.js when its out of html body

Comment: @MYARCH Do you have an error in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you put the javascript code directly in the HTML page or add it to the script using the src attribute on the script. The problem is, you aren't setting a request header with `setRequestHeader()`. Add the following line of code just after `http.open()`, but before `http.send()` and it'll definitely work:

```
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format provides a way to encode name-value pairs.

Comment: Sorry still not work  i add                                                                                              
`http.open('POST', url, true); //----------> always stop her
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
 }
}
http.send(params);`

Comment: I've taken your code and ran it on my machine after adding `http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`. And it works fine. I added the `onreadystatechange` code and it alerts with `username :use`.

Comment: try to run it in  https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor 
try running code it failed to send to php it look like  `http.open('POST', url, true //not defined when js file is out of html body `

Comment: I don't know how you're running php on playcode.io.

Comment: this my php code 
` 
<?php
$A = $_POST['a'];
$B = $_POST['b'];
echo "DATA RECEIVED";
?> `

Comment: It runs for me. Please share the link of your playcode.io source code.

Comment: it not send data and not receive answer from server 
`alert(http.responseText);`    you can create  a php file and upload it in a server and run the file.js  with  playcode.io online compiler  it run but failed to send data and receive answer

Comment: any suggestion ??   Plabon Dutta 
I note that the code when it putted directly in html body it work perfectly but when
i put the js file like this  `    <script src="file.js"></script>` it  stop to execute js file in ` http.open('POST', url, true); ` i detect this fails because i put a alert message after every line of js file

Comment: Plabon Dutta  I upload php on  webhost i note  that i try to inject the js file using xss injection like this <><script src="file.js"></script> and i think that cause the fail of XMLHttpRequest